# use of #define to create a dummy record compatible with C89 std

Tags: c, macros, c89

How can I use #define to create a dummy record according to C89 standards?
I tried:

```
    typedef struct foo{int a; int b;}foo;
    #define DUMMY (foo) {.a=0, .b=0}
```

It works well but gives me a lot of warnings when I compile with -std=c89. Warnings say that this kind of thing is compatible only with C99 standards. Thanks anyone!!

Comment: You can't. C89 does not support neither the compound literals nor designated initializers.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would creating a named object, as with `foo MyDummy = { 0, 0 };` and then defining the macro to refer to it, `#define DUMMY MyDummy`, serve your purposes? (Or, for that matter, simply defining `foo DUMMY = { 0, 0 };` and not using a macro at all.)

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, thanks a lot! yes both solutions could fit! Is the second solution compatible with C89?

Answer (score 0):

In C89, the only values of aggregate (struct/union) type that can be used within a function are named objects, function return values, dereferenced pointers, or members of other aggregates.  While C includes a construct which defines a character array initialized with constant data and yields it as an lvalue [i.e. a string literal], there is no equivalent for any other type.

As noted, if you can create a named static object, you could use:

```
static struct foo const doubleZero = {0,0};
#define DUMMY doubleZero
```

Use of the macro would be compatible with code that uses `#ifdef DUMMY` to determine whether it has already been defined.

If you needed the ability to create an object based upon parameters that might vary, you could use something like:

```
struct fooWrapper { struct foo dat[1]; };
struct fooWrapper makeFoo(int a, int b)
{ struct fooWrapper result; result[0].a=a; result[0].b=b; return result; }
#define MAKEFOO(a,b) (*(fooWrapper((a),(b)).dat))
```

which would then allow code to treat the result of MAKEFOO like an lvalue, thus allowing for e.g.

```
memcpy(whatever, &MAKEFOO(3,5), sizeof (struct foo));
```

The lifetime of the returned wrapper object wouldn't be quite as long as that of a C compound literal, but should be adequate for most purposes where that of a C compound literal would suffice.